# How to load TypeKit fonts into a CKEditor instance using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, typekit

I'm trying to load TypeKit fonts into an instance of the CKEditor via jQuery. Here's my code:

```
$('.ck-blog textarea').ckeditor(function () {
    CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(
      "http://use.typekit.com/zku8fnp.js", 
      function (success) { 
        Typekit.load(); 
        alert(success); }, 
      null, 
      true);
},
{
    resize_enabled: false,
    skin: 'kama',
    height: '500px',
    toolbarCanCollapse: false,
    toolbar_Full: toolbar,
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    autoGrow_onStartup: true,
    templates_replaceContent: false,
    extraPlugins: 'autogrow,wordcount',
    removePlugins: 'resize',
    contentsCss: '/areas/admin/content/css/ckeditor-blog.css',
    templates_files: ['/areas/admin/scripts/ckeditor-templates.js'],
    autoParagraph: false
});
```

I'm getting the success alert after TypeKit is supposed to load but I am not see the fonts load. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

Here what I've managed to assemble after 3 hours of digging over Internet:

```
CKEDITOR.on(
    'instanceReady',
    function(ev) {
        var $script = document.createElement('script'),
            $editor_instance = CKEDITOR.instances[ev.editor.name];

        $script.src = '//use.typekit.com/MYKEY.js';
        $script.onload = function() {
            try{$editor_instance.window.$.Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
        };

        $editor_instance.document.getHead().$.appendChild($script);
    }
);
```

Trick here is to use CKEditor's "window" object, that comes from iframe.

Comment: Because the content in the CKEditor is in an IFRAME I am getting a 403 error. What did you set as the Domain in your kit settings ?

Answer (score 1):

`CKEDITOR.scriptLoader` appears to be used to load assets to the parent window, **not** into the iframe'd `document`. This causes your code above to execute and re-apply the Typekit font to the parent window instead of the iframe.

My solution for this is to set `document.domain` in your parent window, create `<script>` elements dynamically, append them to the `<head>` of the iframe `document`.

**1.** Your Typekit has a domain whitelist. CKEditor will not set set the `<iframe>` tag's `src` attribute to return a valid value in this whitelist unless you specify `document.domain` in your parent window to be a domain on that whitelist.

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

**2.** I created the scripts with lines like

```
script1      = document.newElement('script');
script1.src  = "https://use.typekit.com/MYKEY.js";

script2      = document.newElement('script');
script2.text = "try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}";
```

**3.** I then append these to the dom *(I use jQuery in my project, so that's how I target the element)*

```
head = jQuery('textarea.editor').ckeditorGet().document.getHead().$;
head.appendChild(script1);
head.appendChild(script2);
```

The Typekit fonts are now applied.

Modified for use within the CKEditor setup

```
  editors.ckeditor(function(){
    var head         = this.document.getHead().$,
        script1      = document.newElement("script"),
        script2      = document.newElement("script");

    script1.src  = sprintf("https://use.typekit.com/%s.js", app_typekit_id);
    script2.text = "setTimeout(function(){ try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){} }, 0);";

    head.appendChild(script1);
    head.appendChild(script2);
  },
  {
    //... your custom config
  });
```

Maybe there is a better way than the `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 0);` *(a 0ms delay)*, but leaving just the `try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}` does not give `script1` enough time to be appended and interpreted by the browser to begin blocking. Also note, my use of `sprintf()` above comes from a library *(not native JS)*.