# Accessing Tab Data inside CK Editor

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I have too many ckeditors on one page, which I've been told is the wrong way to go. So, I found this stackflow example of [**Bootstrap Tab Panels**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048401/how-do-i-allow-the-tabs-of-a-bootstrap-tab-to-work-within-the-ckeditor-editor) and it would allow me to reduce the number of ckeditors because I'm thinking I could turn the space under each named tab into an editable space.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/E6Tm4/

```html
<div id="editor1">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#community_kgevents" data-toggle="tab">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgservicelearning" data-toggle="tab">Learning</a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgserviceprojects" data-toggle="tab">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgvolunteering" data-toggle="tab">Volunteer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgcontent1" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $community_kgsubtab1; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgcontent2" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $community_kgsubtab2; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="#community_kgcontent3" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $community_kgsubtab3; ?></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="community_kgevents"><?php echo $community_kgevents; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgservicelearning"><?php echo $community_kgservicelearning; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgserviceprojects"><?php echo $community_kgserviceprojects; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgvolunteering"><?php echo $community_kgvolunteering; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgcontent1"><?php echo $community_kgcontent1; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgcontent2"><?php echo $community_kgcontent2; ?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="community_kgcontent3"><?php echo $community_kgcontent3; ?></div>
</div>
```

The name values in the Tab panes inside the div are the ones I need to capture and send to the mySQL database when I click the Submit button. I can get the Nab tabs named values from input type text fields, but the Tab pane named variables need a ckeditor.

Kyle has created a demo for this at http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/E6Tm4/5/ which works fine, but it isn't what I need because I need to capture all of the named value data when I click the Submit button at the bottom of the web page, which then sends all the data to the mySQL database and subsequently loads the profile web page containing the submitted data from the edit profile web page. Any help would be greatly appreciate on how this can be done.

Comment: Are you planning on having [425 tabs inside the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24169476/1366033)?  Because that would be way too many tabs as well.  I'd say your first mission is to start reducing the number of questions per page.  How long is each answer if there are 425 of them?  Do you really need a rich text editor for them, or will simple text do fine?

Comment: Not if I don't have to.  Yes, it is too many tabs and editors. I think the best thing to do is to separate the page into multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract tab information for all the tabs like this:

```js
var editorContent = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
$(editorContent).find(".tab-pane").each(function() {
    var tabContent = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(tabContent);
});
```

### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/E6Tm4/8/)

Here I'm just logging them, but at the point you're handling each one you can do whatever modifications you need to do to submit it to the server. Preferably over an ajax request.